# Detect the collision between camera and mesh

Tags: collision-detection, mesh, babylonjs

I want a event when the camera touch the mesh it's moove to other place like a portal.

This my camera:

```
function MaCamera(scene, positionCx, positionCy, positionCz) 
{        
    var freeCamera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("FreeCamera", new BABYLON.Vector3(positionCx, positionCy, positionCz), scene);
         freeCamera.rotation = new BABYLON.Vector3(0.5, 0, 0);
         freeCamera.attachControl(canvas, true);
         freeCamera.checkCollisions = true;
         scene.activeCamera = freeCamera;
}
```

And this is my mesh:

```
var drawMirror = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("rectangle", 1, scene);
      drawMirror.scaling = new BABYLON.Vector3(12, 0.1, 20);
      drawMirror.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
      drawMirror.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(positionMx, positionMy, positionMz);
      drawMirror.checkCollisions = true;
```

Answer (score 6):

By turning the native collision detection in BabylonJS you can achieve camera-mesh collisions using a callback.

First, turn on the global collision detection:

```
//Enable global collisions
scene.collisionsEnabled = true;

//Enable camera collisions
camera.checkCollisions = true;

//Enable mesh collision (per mesh)
drawMirror.checkCollisions = true;
```

Second, set the onCollide method of the camera:

```
camera.onCollide = function(collidedMesh) {
    if(collidedMesh.uniqueId === drawMirror.uniqueId) {
        //set the new camera position
        camera.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(13,37,42);
    }
}
```

Here is a quick playground to show how it works. http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#1VLOU4

This is one of many ways to solve this, it all depends on the use case. Note that it is important to set the camera's ellipsoid - this is the bounding box that is moving along with the camera. Collisions are inspected against this bounding box.